# Java TwitchBot/PircBot can't read commands in a .txt file like it has to do

Tags: java, bots, bufferedreader, irc, pircbot

I start coding my own `TwitchBot` in `java`. The bot is working fine, so my idea was, to replace the hardcoded commands with variables. The commands and messages saved in a text file.

`BufferedReader` Class:

```java
try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("censored//lucky.txt"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {

                String arr[] = line.split(" ", 2);

                command = arr[0];
                message = arr[1];

                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Snippet of my `bot/command class`

```java
if(message.toLowerCase().contains(BufferedReader.command)) {
            sendMessage(channel, BufferedReader.message);
        }
```

my `.txt` file:

```
!test1 Argument1 Argument2
!test2 Argument1 Argument2
!test3 Argument1 Argument2
!test4 Argument1 Argument2
```

Everything works fine when I have only 1 `command+message / line` in my text document, but when there are multiple lines, I can't access the commands in the `Twitch Chat`. I know, that the commands are stacking like `!test1` `!test2` `!test3` `!test` this.

So my question is, how do I avoid this? And my fear is, that in my actual code `!test3` uses the message from my `!test1` command.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do here, but it seems like you might need to store you commands and messages in a List or Set. Right now you seem to be overwriting them each time around the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (line != null) 
{
   String arr[] = line.split(" ", 2);
   command = arr[0];
   message = arr[1];
   line = reader.readLine();
}
```

this loop keeps reading each line from the file and overwrites contents of `command` and `message` , that means when you have multiple commands in file - only the last line prevails.

If you want to store multiple commands/messages then the `command`/`message` variables must be of type `java.util.List` or `HashMap`. And then you can match based on contents.

Eg.,

```
Map<String,String> msgMap = new HashMap<>();
while (line != null) 
    {
       String arr[] = line.split(" ", 2);
       if(arr[0]!=null)
         msgMap.put(arr[0],arr[1]);
       line = reader.readLine();
    }
```

Comment: This is a good method ty <3 but I never worked with HashMap so I dont know, how can I implement it in bot/command class? because msgMap.keySet() dont work. I mean the snippet is searching in the message for a single String not a Map of them.

Comment: Map is a key value pair store. If you have the key you can get it with msgMap.get(key)